# <ReferenceArrayInput /> not working with my custom data provider (prisma)

Tags: graphql, react-admin, prisma

I'm currently building a data provider for [prisma](http://prisma.io) based on graphcool's one, and failed at succeeding to make `<ReferenceArrayInput />` working.

The component successfully queries the values of the item and all the possibles values available, but it looks like it's failing when trying to match both. As a result, I get a label saying `At least one of the associated references no longer appears to be available.`, with no values selected.

Here's the data returned by my data provider:

Returned by the `GET_MANY` request to grab actual choices:

```
[
  {
    "id": "cji4xk7ly00k3085444gszh6e",
    "name": "value1",
    "option.id": "cji4xk7lx00k20854ns2bersv",
    "option": {
      "id": "cji4xk7lx00k20854ns2bersv"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "cji4xk7lz00k40854gp876vgn",
    "name": "value2",
    "option.id": "cji4xk7lx00k20854ns2bersv",
    "option": {
      "id": "cji4xk7lx00k20854ns2bersv"
    }
  }
]
```

And the data returned by the `GET_LIST` request to grab all possible values:

```
[
  {
    "id": "cji4xk7lz00k40854gp876vgn",
    "name": "value2",
    "option.id": "cji4xk7lx00k20854ns2bersv",
    "option": {
      "id": "cji4xk7lx00k20854ns2bersv"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "cji4xk7ly00k3085444gszh6e",
    "name": "value1",
    "option.id": "cji4xk7lx00k20854ns2bersv",
    "option": {
      "id": "cji4xk7lx00k20854ns2bersv"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "cjit6nvot00j80954n53vj6vt",
    "name": "1x100ml",
    "option.id": "cjit6dejm00bt0954ts5g2f5g",
    "option": {
      "id": "cjit6dejm00bt0954ts5g2f5g"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "cjit6gu5o00d00954vzfuda0l",
    "name": "19mg",
    "option.id": "cjit6e66i00cb0954u1zlg1i3",
    "option": {
      "id": "cjit6e66i00cb0954u1zlg1i3"
    }
  }
]
```

On the JSX part, here's my code:

```
export const OptionEdit = props => (
  <Edit title="Edit an option" {...props}>
    <SimpleForm>
      <DisabledInput source="id" />
      <TextInput source="name" />
      <ReferenceArrayInput source="values" reference="OptionValue" perPage={100}>
        <SelectArrayInput optionText="name" />
      </ReferenceArrayInput>
    </SimpleForm>
  </Edit>
);
```

I can try to setup something for you to reproduce my issue if needed, I'm hoping that this would be enough for you to help me. If it can help though, here's the repository containing my (very wip) data provider and the dashboard [ra-data-prisma](https://github.com/Weakky/ra-data-prisma/)

Thanks a lot for you help.

### Update:

Here's a codesandbox if you want to try: https://codesandbox.io/s/xvqm6mnyxz?expanddevtools=1&initialpath=App.js&module=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js

Just try to edit a `User`, and see the responses in the console along with the `SelectArrayInput` not being loaded with choices.

And here's the datamodel used for generating the Prisma API used in the codesanbox example:

```
type User {
  id: ID! @unique
  name: String!
  addresses: [Address!]!
}

type Address {
  id: ID! @unique
  city: String!
  user: User!
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it. `react-admin` expects an array of ids to match the resources. All I needed to do was to set the `<ReferenceArrayInput />` `source` prop to `<resource>Ids`. That fixed the issue.